# Limiting distribution of $T_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(2X_i−n)}{n}−3$ where $f_k(x) =\frac{x^k}{k!}e^{−x}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence, asymptotics

> $X_1$, $X_2$,..., are independent random variables. $X_k$ has pdf
>
> $$f_k(x) =\frac{x^k}{k!}e^{−x}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$$
>
> Let
>
> $$T_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(2X_i−n)}{n}−3$$
>
> Consider the sequence $T_1$, $T_2$,.., and give the pmf or pdf of the
>   limiting distribution.

I tried to use the following theorem:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_{T_n}(t)=M_T(t)$$ for all $t$ in a neighborhood of $0$ $\Rightarrow T_n \rightarrow T$

I first note that $f_k(x)\sim Gamma(\alpha=k+1,\beta=1)$ which has mgf $M_{X_k}(t)=\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^{k+1}$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
M_{T_n}(t)
&=M_{\frac{\sum(2X_i−n)}{n}−3}(t)\\\\
&=M_{\frac{2\left(\sum X_i\right)−n^2}{n}−3}(t)\\\\
&=M_{\frac{2}{n}\left(\sum X_i\right)-n−3}(t)\\\\
&=e^{-(n+3)t}M_{\sum X_i}\left(\frac{2t}{n}\right)\\\\
&=e^{-(n+3)t}M_{X_1}\left(\frac{2t}{n}\right)\cdot M_{X_2}\left(\frac{2t}{n}\right)\cdots M_{X_n}\left(\frac{2t}{n}\right)\\\\
&=e^{-(n+3)t}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2t}{n}}\right)^{2}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2t}{n}}\right)^{3}\cdots \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2t}{n}}\right)^{n+1}\\\\
&=e^{-(n+3)t}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2t}{n}}\right)^{\frac{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}{2}-1}
\end{align*}$$

Then the next step would be to take

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(e^{-(n+3)t}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2t}{n}}\right)^{\frac{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}{2}-1}\right)$$

which looks rather messy. I am afraid I made a mistake somewhere. Is there a more simple approach to finding the limiting distribution?

I have also tried taking

$$\begin{align*}
F_{T_n}(t)
&=P(T_n\leq t)\\\\
&=P\left(\frac{\sum(2X_i−n)}{n}−3\leq t\right)\\\\
&=P\left(\sum X_i \leq \frac{n(t+3)+n^2}{2}\right)\\\\
\end{align*}$$

but I don't think this method wouldn't work as the $X_k$'s are not identically distributed.

I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction. Hopefully then I can finish it from there.

Comment: Are you saying that $(k+1)E\sim X_k$?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it should be $\sum_1^{k+1} E_i$

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, my answer above is wrong, you'll have to do a double sum instead:
$$X_i = \sum_i^{k+1} E_i$$
... where E_i is an exponential distribution, [here's the reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties):

"If X ~ Gamma(α, θ) and Y ~ Gamma(β, θ) are independently distributed, then ... X + Y, which is Gamma(α + β, θ)-distributed"

 So:
$$\sum_i X_i = \sum_i \sum_1^{i+1} E_i$$

Comment: So then would $E_{i}\sim exp(i)$? If so, wouldn't that lead to the same problem as before?

Comment: Not necessarily, you will be able to write that sum as one sum (instead of a double sum) of independent exponentials, which will be a single gamma distribution. Btw, $E_i \sim Exponential(1)$, not i.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thank you. Could you clarify what the double sum is doing? So we're adding $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-1$ exponential random variables, each with mean $1$? Is that correct?

Comment: Actually you don't even need the exponential, although it makes life a bit easier. So, we have a sum of gamma distributions yeah? The sum of $X_i$ would be Gamma(2, 1) + Gamma(3, 1) + Gamma(4, 1) + ... Gamma(n+1, 1). Which is essentially Gamma($\sum_1^{n} k + 1$, 1). 

So your answer should be, [based on this result](https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/254965.image0.png): $density(Gamma(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n, 1)) \leq RHS$.

Sorry if I confused you initially, messed up myself there :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be $Gamma\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-1\right)$?

Comment: Both answers are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and take it from here. The resulting CDF looks like it will be messy!

Comment: Your limit becomes much less messy upon taking logarithms.